# Selecting a variable range, but with constant last value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeing quite some of methods to select a range, but not for my problem. I want to select a variable range, and i think the best way is to tell it to go upto a certain value. (then copy paste etc)

Within the range (one column) the number of rows will vary regularly. Also, there will be several empty rows within that range, and below it will be more full rows.

So, i'm thinking i put in an Anchor value, and always select the range upto that value, so adding and removing rows will not interfere. But how do i do that...

edit: So it's important i only copy upto that anchor value, what is below it must not be copied...

Anyone?

Solved As;

```
 Set EndCell = ActiveSheet.Range("L7:L45").Find("AnchorSec", LookIn:=xlValues)
ActiveSheet.Range("L7", EndCell).Copy
AAR.Worksheets("Portfolio_2016").Range("K7").PasteSpecial
```

I still have to be careful with the range in which it looks for AnchorSec, but that could in theory be upto L1000 or where ever.

Answer (score 0):

As an example if you were looking to have the range C1:C100 to be variable, you can just type C:C there. There is no need to specify the row numbers. (Am not sure if I have gotten your problem correctly. Sorry can't type this in the comments, don't have the reputation)

Comment: But i only want to copy Column C upto that Anchor value. What is below there must not be copied. However, where the anchor value is varies because i add and delete data (trades)

Comment: Ah ok, I don't think I got your problem completely the last time. A sub-Qn: how do you identify the anchor value?

Comment: Well that can be anything. It's how i basically think it should go. Write something that selects upto the cell that contains X, however, where that cell is varies.

Comment: I understand it is variable and can be anything. I presume you will identify it by a value say X? Then before the logic can be built in, would it be the only cell that has value X in it (or multiple instances in the column)? Is the X numeric or alphabetic? Maybe if you can illustrate with an example?

Comment: yeah. Just call it 'Anchor', i guess. So, for example select c7 to c(Anchor) Where of course, the location of Anchor changes regulary

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

This what i need; Find a value, and use it's address as the end of my range. See if i can apply this.